# How do you search a cell for text, cell might have more than one value in it

Tags: vba, search, text, cell

I am trying to make and automated report searching cells for text and converting them into values. so one cell could have car, van, car, truck next cell could have just car.

```
Sub try_to_find_text ()
Dim ALCell As Range
Dim car As Integer
Dim van As Integer
Dim truck As Integer
Dim digger As Integer


    For Each ALCell In ActiveSheet.Range("E21:E1000")
    
        Select Case ALCell.Value
        
            Case Is <> ""
            
                        Dim Search1, Where1
                        Search1 = "car"
                        Where1 = InStr(ActiveCell.Text, Search1)
                            If Where1 Then
                                car = car + 1
                           
                            End If
            
            
            Case Is = "van"
            van = van + 1
            
            Case Is = "truck"
            truck = truck + 1
            
            Case Is = "digger"
            HCAS = HCAS + 1
            
          
            Case Is = ""
        
           
        
        End Select

Next ALCell
ActiveSheet.Range("B13").Value = car
ActiveSheet.Range("C13").Value = van
ActiveSheet.Range("D13").Value = truck
ActiveSheet.Range("E13").Value = digger
End Sub
```

The above will find the cells that have the specific value in the "" but if there is more e.g. car, van this will be missed in the count. at the top I am trying to create a loop for the active cell text but this doesn't work any help would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to have an inner loop which iterates over an array obtained from the worksheet cell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub try_to_find_text()
Dim ALCell As Range
Dim car As Integer
Dim van As Integer
Dim truck As Integer
Dim digger As Integer



    For Each ALCell In ActiveSheet.Range("E21:E1000")
    
        Dim myVehicle As Variant
        Dim myVehicles As Variant
        myVehicles = TriageToArray(ALCell.Value,",")
        For Each myVehicle In myVehicles
        
            Select Case myVehicle
            
                Case Is = "car"
                
                    car = car + 1  
     
                Case Is = "van"

                    van = van + 1
                
                Case Is = "truck"

                    truck = truck + 1
                
                Case Is = "digger"

                    HCAS = HCAS + 1
                  
                Case Is = ""
                       
            End Select
            
        Next

Next ALCell

ActiveSheet.Range("B13").Value = car
ActiveSheet.Range("C13").Value = van
ActiveSheet.Range("D13").Value = truck
ActiveSheet.Range("E13").Value = digger
End Sub


Public Function TriageToArray(ByVal ipString As String, Optional ByVal ipSeparator As String = " ") As Variant

    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Split(ipString, ipSeparator)
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    
        myArray(myIndex) = LCase$(Trim$(myArray(myIndex)))
        
    Next

    TriageToArray = myArray
    
End Function
```

Comment: Amazing thanks, just had to remove the car bit and add like the van and it worked a charm. thank you so much